# Best approach for multiple Django projects and async emails

Tags: python, django, celery, amazon-ses

I'm using Django 2 with Python 3.5 in a Ubuntu server.
I have multiple Django projects, this projects are using the same virutalenv, because they have the same source code.

For making the email sending async, I'm using post-office app for Django, this requires to run a crontab every minute to send the queued emails in database.
But this approach is getting hard to maintain with a great number of Django projects in the same server, so every minute I have a great CPU demand spike.
The emails are being handled by AWS SES.

I'm thinking in use Celery with RabbitMQ, but this is getting confusing for me.
Will I have multiple Celery and one RabbitMQ instances?
Can this be done without interference?

Are there a way to use just one async task process, an alternative for Celery and RebbitMQ?

Comment: What do you mean by instances?  processes or servers?

Comment: Are multiple Django projects running under apache with vhosts

Answer (score 0):

Assuming instances means ec2 instances, you can have as many (or as few) celery instances and as many (or few) rabbitmq instances as you like (rabbit mq can be clustered).  All you have to do is make sure all of your producers (your django webservers) and all of your consumers (your celery workers) point to the same rabbit mq url as a broker.

Note, since you're using AWS, you can just as easily set up celery using [Amazon's SQS service](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/sqs.html#using-amazon-sqs)  or by [using AWS_hosted redis via elasticache](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html).